# Onclick function that changes the css of a element

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I now have this onclick function:

```
<p  onclick="open3()" >Uw tuin blijft mooi door vakkundig en regelmatig onderhoud.</p>


function open3 () 
{
    document.getElementById("c").style.display = "block";
}
```

What I want is that when I clicked on open three that it somehow changes it's value so I can click on it again to set `style.display` to `none`.

I tried this with a Boolean that set's it to `true` or `false` and then changes that but that didn't work

Comment: Do you really want to change the function called or do you want to toggle the visibility?

Comment: Just change the `open3` function to use an `if` statement that checks if `.style.display === "block"`, and if so, set it to `"none"`, else to `"block"`.

Comment: ...if you really wanted to change the function, that can be done too, but it would be an unusual approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `if` statement that checks the current value of the applied style and changes it appropriately.

Using this approach you don't need to declare (and keep) any additional variable in your code, while still being able to achieve the desired effect.

An example is shown below.

```
function open3 () {
    var c = document.getElementById('c');
    if (c.style.display === 'block') {
       c.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
       c.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a check in the function:

```
function open3 () {
 var c = document.getElementById("c");
 if (c.style.display === 'block') {
   c.style.display = 'none';
 } else {
   c.style.display = 'block';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pure Javascript:

```
function open3 () 
            {
                if (document.getElementById("c").style.display == "block")
                    document.getElementById("c").style.display = "none";
                else
                     document.getElementById("c").style.display = "block";
            }
```

Or you can use jQuery instead:

```
function opne3()
{
   $("#c").toggle();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: In your first example you should cache `document.getElementById("c")`in a variable.

Comment: thanks this is perfect and now i see it it's much easier than i imagined

Answer (score 0):

My approach is slightly different and creates a toggler function that returns a function to toggle whatever elements you pass into it with an initial state. You can keep reusing this function whenever you need to toggle an element so you don't repeat code.

```
var toggler = function(el, init) {
  var flag = init;
  return function(e) {
    flag = !flag;
    el.style.display = flag ? 'block' : 'none';
  };
}
```

Create a new function passing in the element to be toggled and its initial state.

```
var toggleC = toggler(document.querySelector('#c'), false);
```

Remove the inline JS (best practice) and use `addEventListener` to target the element instead.

```
document.querySelector('#clicker').addEventListener('click', toggleC);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rr9u47x2/8/)

Answer (score 0):

A short version of the if/else answers on this page:

```
function open3 () {
    var c = document.getElementById('c');
    c.style.display = (c.style.display == 'block' ? 'none': 'block');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**HTML:**

```
<p id="togglethingy">Uw tuin blijft mooi door vakkundig en regelmatig onderhoud.
```

**CSS:**

```
#togglethingy{
    display:block;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
    var $tog_ele = $("#togglethingy")
    $tog_ele.click(function() {
        $tog_ele.toggle();
    });
});
```